# Select according to string ending

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In my DB, I store various version numbers, like the following :

```
OBJNAME
Fix_6.0.0a.1
Fix_6.0.0a.2
```

I would like to sort them not according to last version element (the number behind the last `.` character. How do I write such SQL statement ?

I guess it's something like:

```
  SELECT SUBSTR(INSTR(OBJNAME, ".", -1)) as LAST_VERSION, OBJNAME 
    FROM MY_TABLE 
ORDER BY LAST_VERSION
```

But what is the exact syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version is

```
select TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(OBJNAME,INSTR(OBJNAME,'.',-1)+1,LENGTH(OBJNAME))) as LAST_VERSION, OBJNAME from MY_TABLE order by LAST_VERSION
```

Comment: Technically something like `SUBSTR(OBJNAME,INSTR(OBJNAME,'.',-1)+1,LENGTH(OBJNAME) - INSTR(OBJNAME,'.',-1))` would be more "beautiful" - you extract the exact amount of symbols you need :) Or, as far as I remember, you may even omit last parameter of `substr` - it will return you everything after the starting symbol then.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know which sql-software you are using, but you should have a look at substr and instr parameters. in you case you are passing 3 parameters to instr and 1 parameter in substr. but substr normally requires more. insert some blanks to get an overview of your statement, especially for the substr.... as LAST_VERSION. then you will see. wrong param count.